# setting events in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have this following code in cpp. I need to port it into Objective C. I am new to Objective C.

How to set the events and start threads in Objective C.

```
RS232Timer::RS232Timer()
{
 m_hThreadEvent = CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL);
 m_hThreadControlEvent = CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL);
 m_bThreadActive = false;
 m_bRunThread = false;
}

void RS232Timer::startThread()
{
 m_bRunThread = true;
 (void)ResetEvent(m_hThreadEvent);
 (void)ResetEvent(m_hThreadControlEvent);
 (void)AfxBeginThread(timeoutThread,(void*)this); //timeoutThread is another function
 if((waitForSingleObject(m_hThreadControlEvent,1500)!=WAIT_OBJECT_O)||!m_bThreadActive)
 {
  assert(FALSE);
  m_bThread = false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not only a matter of porting from C++ to ObjC, but also from win32 to Cocoa...

I would suggest you to use [NSThread](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSCondition](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Extremely useful is the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH1-SW1), specifically when it comes to [synchronization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html).

No easy "statement-to-statement" porting is possible, I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this might help you:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

[object runSomeLongOperation:^{
    // your own code here.
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(semaphore);
```